# How to cancel the \hypersetup in 0rg-mode of Emacs

Tags: latex, org-mode

Org-mode is a power editor. I use it to write scientific notes and produce them into tex/PDF files.

When I produce .org file into .tex or .pdf file, some codes are generated automatically by org-mode, such as:

```
 \hypersetup{
    pdfkeywords={},
    pdfsubject={},
    pdfcreator={Emacs Org-mode version 7.8.11}}
```

Those codes make some information occupied the first page of PDF file, that is useless for me.
How to prevent those codes from appearing on the tex-file produced and its PDF?

Comment: The solution likely depends on how your `.org` file looks.  Perhaps you can edit your question by including the org-mode header information for your `.org` file --- just those lines with `#+...` before your actual text.

Comment: Related: [what are the influences after cancelling \hypersetup in org-mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11366425)

Answer (score 12):

I use this in my init file:

`(setq org-latex-with-hyperref nil)`

Then you have to put your own hyper setup in where you want it.