# what are the influences after cancelling \hypersetup in org-mode?

Tags: latex, org-mode

I make pdf in org-mode with my own preamble, but the PDF or tex file generated always appear the information resulting from:

```
(format "\\hypersetup{\n  pdfkeywords={%s},\n  pdfsubject={%s},\n  pdfcreator={%s}}\n"
(org-export-latex-fontify-headline keywords)
(org-export-latex-fontify-headline description)
(concat "Emacs Org-mode version " org-version))
```

those cods locate in ~/.emacs.d/org-7.8.11/lisp/org-latex.el

I cancelled it to prevent the useless information appearing at the first page of its PDF-file.
However is it OK to delete such codes without any function lost?

what influences will be caused by this action?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I know how it is.

add the code into your preamble :

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

all are solved.

Answer (score 3):

In that same file you mention, (`lisp/org-latex.el`), it suggests

```
org-latex-hyperref-template...
Set it to the empty string to ignore the command completely.
```

So the following should work

```
(setq org-latex-hyperref-template "")
```

Alas, I've reading downloaded source code not the same as my current `org` version, so this didn't work. `apropos` may be an easy fix, so

```
M-x apropos RET hyperref RET
```

leads me to the variable `org-latex-with-hyperref`, so now I try

```
(setq org-latex-with-hyperref nil)
```

This worked for me.